# Recording App Video Previews with QuickTime

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, osx-mavericks, quicktime

I have OSX 10.9.5 and I'll use QuickTime and iMovie for my video preview for app. When I do New Screen Recordings with QuickTime the simulator is recorded but so are the mouse arrow clicks. How do I completely remove the mouse arrow from the recording? Also, I connected my iOS device and then in QuickTime clicked on New Movie Recording as it states on Apple documents then the FaceTime camera appears but never an option to play iOS device. What gives? Where do I click iOS device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have OSX 10.9.5

That's your problem with the iOS device recording. This is an OS X 10.10 feature only.

Moreover, the current Xcode is available only for OS X 10.10. So step one is: upgrade your system.

> How do I completely remove the mouse arrow from the recording

I would recommend using ScreenFlow to make recordings of your computer screen. It lets you do this and much, much more.

Comment: Do you know if I upgrade to 10.10 Yosemite would it be possible that the upgrade delete my Xcode project files on desktop from the OSX 10.9.5 ?

Comment: Don't worry, it won't. In fact, I've upgraded several machines from Mavericks to Yosemite and in every case it was the easiest, cleanest upgrade you can imagine. Everything "just worked" afterwards; my files and preferences were all preserved. Your old Xcode, of course, will no longer work, but the new version (6.2, or even 7) will open all your old projects and won't harm them.